disable ssl handshake for javax.websocket
I am using javax websocket to test a websocket server.
However I am getting the following error when running the test
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Here's my test:
@Test
    void firstTest(){
        try {
            // open websocket
            final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI("wss://167.254.200.64:30472/vmc/websocket/faultmanagement?bearer=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR"));

             .....
            }catch(...){
             .....
            }
}

and here's WebsocketClientEndpoint:
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

@ClientEndpoint
public class WebsocketClientEndpoint {
    Session userSession = null;
    private MessageHandler messageHandler;

    public WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI) {
        try {
            WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    @OnOpen
    ......
}

And here's my error
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection to [wss://167.254.200.64:30472/vmc/websocket/faultmanagement?bearer=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJCMHpvMmhBaDJ6dWYyT0wwVTd5b3VCaTcxdDB3dk8yNTNfb0N4a205Yy1BIn0.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.eV4K_TPvhsLMq-N6xXTQuCL4b54Fvoxz57nQL9zWE6F120-D3Ls-7mzQHxbtGOBzUF0XlGJhLINbK1OaUgmgmWw8inW2uXeMs0Q5NcaULCkFe_Vs4ye9LVcZvJJlsE8pAvd-KGI8NDSz8CrbmpSSN6j4UVlCYloEuqoO3QTd1TJN8TKoXuIlMWGErzYH70WYC6giYIbu5jMhnMw6euwiQxTB0GXohtEYoKL1AY3S7wqBU_CXwDw15GpdgxVaUVcTibneyO1huuCstvE5O242GMscABuY-KuwGn9lptD467c29J6M-WW-Rdw-YTmavZBzSo6ApoOfCbTHCblddHyLUQ] failed

    at com.fujitsu.fnc.vmc.fault.notification.northbound.util.WebsocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:31)
    at com.fujitsu.fnc.vmc.fault.notification.northbound.StressTest.firstTest(StressTest.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection to [wss://167.254.200.64:30472/vmc/websocket/faultmanagement?bearer=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJCMHpvMmhBaDJ6dWYyT0wwVTd5b3VCaTcxdDB3dk8yNTNfb0N4a205Yy1BIn0.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.eV4K_TPvhsLMq-N6xXTQuCL4b54Fvoxz57nQL9zWE6F120-D3Ls-7mzQHxbtGOBzUF0XlGJhLINbK1OaUgmgmWw8inW2uXeMs0Q5NcaULCkFe_Vs4ye9LVcZvJJlsE8pAvd-KGI8NDSz8CrbmpSSN6j4UVlCYloEuqoO3QTd1TJN8TKoXuIlMWGErzYH70WYC6giYIbu5jMhnMw6euwiQxTB0GXohtEYoKL1AY3S7wqBU_CXwDw15GpdgxVaUVcTibneyO1huuCstvE5O242GMscABuY-KuwGn9lptD467c29J6M-WW-Rdw-YTmavZBzSo6ApoOfCbTHCblddHyLUQ] failed
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:428)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:122)
    at com.fujitsu.fnc.vmc.fault.notification.northbound.util.WebsocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:29)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WrapperFuture.get(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:489)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:320)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:303)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:298)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1076)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1010)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WebSocketSslHandshakeThread.run(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:381)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 15 more


Process finished with exit code -1



“…here's my error” I’m afraid that image is unreadable.  Edit your question and include the stack trace as text, not as an image.

added the log as requested

Looks like a standard SSL certificate problem.  Was the certificate that is used by that server issued by a valid, trusted Certificate Authority (CA)?
